# Past tense: "happen to have" or "happened to have"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, is-it-a-rule, fast-speech-rules

#### Which is the proper (i.e. grammatically correct) response?

---

> **Alice:** "The earth is flat, and the sky is green."

**Bob:** "The earth is round, and the sky is blue."

> **Alice:** "Can you provide indisputable proof of these claims?"

**Bob:** "No. It's just something I *happen to have* observed."

---

**Bob:** "No. It's just something I *happened to have* observed."

Comment: If you had used the plain infinitive *to observe*, you would need to use past tense *happened*. But because you're using the perfect infinitive *to have observed*, you should use present tense.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But what is a plain/perfect infinitive?

Comment: *to have observed* is a [perfect infinitive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked), because of the *have*. And I should have called *to observe* the [simple infinitive](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive), which is the standard terminology. The perfect infinitive also encompasses the past, so *I happened to have observed* would generally be used if you were talking about two past times – one time in the past that is the focus of the conversation, and earlier times in the past when you observed it.

Comment: Although note that in speech, *I happened to have observed* is nearly indistinguishable from *I happen to have observed.*

Comment: Either one is grammatically correct.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, that's what led to the question. It's something often encountered in colloquial speech; I don't think I've ever seen it written. There are probably more correct ways to say the same thing while transcending the problem altogether, but I was curious about this particular example.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor has written, only *I happen to have observed* is correct. Whereas *have observed* is perfect, it describes knowledge due to a past experience—similar to the Present Perfect tense. The verb *happen*, acting as [stative verb](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stative), tells that the speaker is referring to his **present** knowledge.

Compare:

1. I happen to know your father.
   (*I know your father.*)
2. I happen to have known your father.
   (*I used to know your father.*)

*happen* here emphasizes the random nature of this circumstance and the irrelevance of its causes to the conscious efforts of the three persons involved.

Comment: Last year, I  happened to have observed that his comments were unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

From the corpus of the [*Longman Dictionary*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/happen-to-do-something), it seems the general past tense form is ‘happened to do’. Although I think ‘happen to have observed’ sounds better in your example, as it is not really describing a past case.

(A search led me here because of the title, so I do not think my answer is completely irrelevant.)